# Preventing circular joining, recursive searches

Tags: mysql, recursion

So in my situation I have three tables: `list`, `item` and `list_relation`.

Each `item` will be linked to a list through the `list_id` foreign key.

the `list_relation` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE list_relation
    (
        parent_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        child_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

        UNIQUE(parent_id, child_id)

        FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
            REFERENCES list (id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE,    

        FOREIGN KEY (child_id)
            REFERENCES list (id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

I want to be be able to inherit from multiple lists as well (which includes the related items).

For example I have list: 1, 2, 3.

I was wondering if there was any SQL way to prevent there from being a circular relation. E.g.

List 1 inherits from List 3, List 2 inherits from List 1, List 3 inherits from List 1.

`1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1`

My current idea is that I would have to find out whether it would be circular by validating the desired inheritance first then inserting it into the DB.

Comment: Usually "list" and "item" imply a 1:many relationship, not "many:many".  So, which is it?  Then give a sample of table data that shows the "loop".  Please don't use the word "inherit", it means nothing in SQL.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, I'm not very familiar with SQL terminology so I just use whatever terms I feel are relevant. `list` and `item` are indeed a `1 to many` relationship, but since I wish to have a list have a parent list, this means that when I call `select list 2`, it is actually showing `list 1 + list 2`

Comment: If you had list 3 is a child of list 1, list 2 is a child of list 1, and list 3 is a child of list 2, for your purposes, would you consider that to be circular?

Comment: "Parent" and "child" is often used to refer to a _single_ table and a "self join" to implement a "hierarchy"  But you seem to have two tables "lists", and "items", plus a many-to-many relation table between them?  Changing "parent_id" to "list_id" and "child_id" to "item_id" would have prevented my confusion.

Answer (score 7):

If you use *MySQL 8.0* or *MariaDB 10.2* (or higher) you can try *recursive CTEs (common table expressions)*.

Assuming the following schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `list_relation` (
  `child_id`  int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`,`parent_id`)
);
insert into list_relation (child_id, parent_id) values
    (2,1),
    (3,1),
    (4,2),
    (4,3),
    (5,3);
```

Now you try to insert a new row with `child_id  = 1` and `parent_id = 4`. But that would create cyclic relations (*1->4->2->1* and *1->4->3->1*), which you want to prevent. To find out if a reverse relation already exists, you can use the following query, which will show all parents of *list 4* (including inherited/transitive parents):

```
set @new_child_id  = 1;
set @new_parent_id = 4;

with recursive rcte as (
  select *
  from list_relation r
  where r.child_id = @new_parent_id
  union all
  select r.*
  from rcte
  join list_relation r on r.child_id = rcte.parent_id
)
select * from rcte
```

The result would be:

```
child_id | parent_id
       4 |         2
       4 |         3
       2 |         1
       3 |         1
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYG9fBee6xCSbAseZbvasE/0)

You can see in the result, that the *list 1* is one of the parents of *list 4*, and you wouldn't insert the new record.

Since you only want to know if *list 1* is in the result, you can change the last line to

```
select * from rcte where parent_id = @new_child_id limit 1
```

or to

```
select exists (select * from rcte where parent_id = @new_child_id)
```

BTW: You can use the same query to prevent redundant relations.
Assuming you want to insert the record with `child_id = 4` and `parent_id = 1`. This would be redundant, since *list 4* already inherits *list 1* over *list 2* and *list 3*. The following query would show you that:

```
set @new_child_id  = 4;
set @new_parent_id = 1;

with recursive rcte as (
  select *
  from list_relation r
  where r.child_id = @new_child_id
  union all
  select r.*
  from rcte
  join list_relation r on r.child_id = rcte.parent_id
)
select exists (select * from rcte where parent_id = @new_parent_id)
```

And you can use a similar query to get all inherited items:

```
set @list = 4;

with recursive rcte (list_id) as (
  select @list
  union distinct
  select r.parent_id
  from rcte
  join list_relation r on r.child_id = rcte.list_id
)
select distinct i.*
from rcte
join item i on i.list_id = rcte.list_id
```

Answer (score 4):

**For those who do no have MySQL 8.0** or Maria DB and would like to use recursive method in MySQL 5.7. *I just hope you don't have to exceed the max rec.depth of 255 [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sp_recursion_depth):)*

MySQL does not allow recursive functions, however it does allow recursive procedures. Combining them both you can have nice little function which you can use in any select command.

the recursive sp will take two input parameters and one output. First input is the ID you are searching the node tree for, second input is used by the sp to preserve results during the execution. Third parameter is the output parameter which carries the the end result.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_list_relation_recursive`(
    in itemId       text,
    in iPreserve    text,
    out oResult     text

)
BEGIN

    DECLARE ChildId text default null;

    IF (coalesce(itemId,'') = '') then
        -- when no id received retun whatever we have in the preserve container
        set oResult = iPreserve;
    ELSE
        -- add the received id to the preserving container
        SET iPreserve = concat_ws(',',iPreserve,itemId);
        SET oResult = iPreserve;

        SET ChildId = 
        (
            coalesce(
            (
                Select 
                    group_concat(TNode.child_id separator ',') -- get all children
                from 
                    list_relation as TNode 
                WHERE 
                    not find_in_set(TNode.child_id,     iPreserve) -- if we don't already have'em
                    AND find_in_set(TNode.parent_id,    itemId) -- from these parents
            )
        ,'')
        );

        IF length(ChildId) >0 THEN
            -- one or more child found, recursively search again for further child elements
            CALL sp_list_relation_recursive(ChildId,iPreserve,oResult);
        END IF;

    END IF;

    -- uncomment this to see the progress looping steps
    -- select ChildId,iPreserve,oResult;
END
```

**test this:**

```
SET MAX_SP_RECURSION_DEPTH = 250;
set @list = '';
call test.sp_list_relation_recursive(1,'',@list);
select @list;

+----------------+
|     @list      |
+----------------+
| ,1,2,3,6,4,4,5 |
+----------------+
```

don't mind about the duplicate parents or extra commas, we just want to know if an element exist in the node without having much if's and whens.

Looks fine sofar, but SP can't be used in select command so we just create wrapper function for this sP.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_list_relation_recursive`(
    NodeId int
) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    /*
        Returns a tree of nodes
        branches out all possible branches
    */
    DECLARE mTree mediumtext;
    SET MAX_SP_RECURSION_DEPTH = 250;


    call sp_list_relation_recursive(NodeId,'',mTree);

    RETURN mTree;
END
```

**now check it in action:**

```
SELECT 
    *,
    FN_LIST_RELATION_RECURSIVE(parent_id) AS parents_children
FROM
    list_relation;

+----------+-----------+------------------+
| child_id | parent_id | parents_children |
+----------+-----------+------------------+
|        1 |         7 | ,7,1,2,3,6,4,4,5 |
|        2 |         1 |   ,1,2,3,6,4,4,5 |
|        3 |         1 |   ,1,2,3,6,4,4,5 |
|        4 |         2 |             ,2,4 |
|        4 |         3 |           ,3,4,5 |
|        5 |         3 |           ,3,4,5 |
|        6 |         1 |   ,1,2,3,6,4,4,5 |
|       51 |        50 |           ,50,51 |
+----------+-----------+------------------+
```

your inserts will look like this:

```
insert into list_relation (child_id,parent_id)
select
    -- child, parent
    1,6
where 
    -- parent not to be foud in child's children node
    not find_in_set(6,fn_list_relation_recursive(1));
```

1,6 should add 0 records. However 1,7 should work.

As always, i'm just proving the concept, you guys are more than welcome 
to tweak the sp to return a parent's children node, or child's parent node. Or have two separate SP for each node tree or even all combined so from a single single id it returns all parents and children.

**Try it.. it's not that hard :)**

Answer (score 2):

Q: *[is there] any SQL way to prevent a circular relation*

A: SHORT ANSWER

There's no declarative constraint that would prevent an INSERT or UPDATE from creating a circular relation (as described in the question.)

But a combination of a `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger could prevent  it, using queries and/or procedural logic to detect that successful completion of the INSERT or UPDATE would cause a circular relation.

When such a condition is detected, the triggers would need to raise an error to prevent the INSERT/UPDATE operation from completing.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't better to put a column `parent_id` inside the list table?

Then you can get the list tree by a query with `LEFT JOIN` on the list table, matching the `parent_id` with the `list_id`, e.g:

```
SELECT t1.list_id, t2.list_id, t3.list_id
FROM list AS t1
LEFT JOIN list as t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.list_id
LEFT JOIN list as t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.list_id
WHERE t1.list_id = #your_list_id#
```

Is it a solution to your case?
Anyway, I suggest you to read about managing hierarchical data in mysql, you can find a lot about this issue!

Comment: "I want to be be able to inherit from multiple lists as well" - So it's a many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind if you need to add an additional table?

A SQL way and efficient way to do this is to create an additional table which contains **ALL** parents for every child. And then check to see if the potential child exists in the parent list of the current node before the inheritance is established.

The `parent_list` table would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_list (
  list_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  parent_list_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (list_id, parent_list_id)
);
```

---

Now, let's start at the very beginning.

1. 2 inherit from 1 and 4.
   `parent_list` is empty, which means both 1 and 4 have no parents. So it's fine in this case.
   After this step, `parent_list` should be:

   > list_id, parent_list_id
   >   2, 1
   >   2, 4
2. 3 inherit from 2.
   2 have two parents, 1 and 4. 3 isn't one of them. So it's fine again.
   Now `parent_list` becomes(Note that **2's parents should be 3's parents also**):

   > list_id, parent_list_id
   >   2, 1
   >   2, 4
   >   3, 1
   >   3, 4
   >   3, 2
3. 4 inherit from 3.
   4 exists in 3's parent list. This will lead to a cycle. NO WAY!

---

To check whether the cycle will happen, you just need one simple SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM parent_list 
WHERE list_id = potential_parent_id AND parent_list_id = potential_child_id;
```

Want to do all these things with one call? Apply a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'inherit'(
IN in_parent_id INT UNSIGNED,
IN in_child_id INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
          ROLLBACK;
          SELECT -1;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM parent_list WHERE list_id = in_parent_id AND parent_list_id = in_child_id) THEN
        SET result = 1; -- just some error code
    ELSE
        -- do your inserting here

        -- update parent_list
        INSERT INTO parent_list (SELECT in_child_id, parent_list_id FROM parent_list WHERE list_id = in_parent_id);
        INSERT INTO parent_list VALUES (in_child_id, in_parent_id);
    END IF;

    COMMIT;
    SELECT result;
END
```

When it comes to a multiple inheritance, just call `inherit` multiple times.

Comment: i feel like I could just do the same using a recursive CTE

Comment: @A.Lau Well, I thought about the recursive way when I first looked at this question. But soon I gave it up. Firstly, that really depends on how you organize your data of `list_relation`. Secondly, the inheritance hierarchy might be very complicated. Even though you can work it out with recursive CTE, it must be complex and super slow.

Comment: It would really just be looking if `parent_id` had any other `parent_id`s, Though I haven't implemented it yet so I wouldn't really know.

Comment: In short, the recursive way is unsure, slow and high risk. If I were you I won't take that in most cases. The second way is definitly simple, clear and efficient. But it does have a shortcoming, that is, it takes more spaces. If there really is a recursive way, it becomes a time-space trade off problem actually.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. If you are looking for a recursive way anyway, you should provide more details about how your tables work. Then I can try to find it out. But I still have to say that it would be very slow and complicated even it really exists.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provide, the errant relationship is simple. It's the 3 -> 1 and 1-> 3 relationships. You could simply look for the inverse relationships when inserting a new row. If it exists, don't insert the new row.

If you add an auto-incrementing column, you could then identify the offending rows specifically.

On the other hand, if you are looking at existing rows, you could identify the errant rows using a simple SQL statement like:

```
SELECT
    a.parent_id,
    a.child_id
FROM list_relation a
JOIN list_relation b
ON a.child_id = b.parent_id AND a.parent_id = b.child_id
```

If you add an auto-incrementing column, you could then identify the offending rows specifically.

Your question title includes the word "prevent", so I presume you want to avoid adding the rows. To do so, you would need a ON BEFORE INSERT trigger that checks for an existing row and prevents the insert. You could also use an ON BEFORE UPDATE trigger to prevent existing rows from being changed to values that would be a problem.

Comment: This will not handle nth depth relations. IOW, if the "circular" relation is more than 1 depth. Example: 3 is child of 1, 2 is child of 1 and 3 is child of 2. If the relationships can be several levels deep, you would have to use a loop to build a list of relationships, an see if the parent_id and child_id of a particular row are found in the other relationships.