# How to detect circular dependency in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table which stores a parent reference. The parent reference is the another entry in same table.

Table structure is something like

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ParentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `ParentId` (`ParentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `mytable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentId`) REFERENCES `mytable` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

How to find circular/cyclic dependency in hierarchy or sub-hierarchy? We don't want to find it necessarily at the time of insert. We can run the solution post data is inserted too. We are using Mysql version 5.7

Comment: See the following answer in the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683053/5389997